# Help with proof that if $g \circ f$ is onto and $f$ is not onto then there is no contradiction

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering if the following argument makes some sly move that I am not detecting:

> **Lemma**
>
> Let $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to C$. If $g\circ f$ is onto and $f$ is non onto then there is no contradiction.
>
> **Tentatively Sly Proof**
>
> Assume that there was a contradiction and that for some $c \in C$ there exists no $a \in A$ such that $(g\circ f)(a) = c$. But that violates the assumption that the composition is surjective.

Here's what I think is a more transparent proof.

> **Alternate Proof**
>
> By assuming the composition is onto, $g$ is onto. We will show that if $f$ is not onto then it can, but is not necessarily the case, that $g \circ f$ is onto.
>
> Firstly, if $g$ is onto then $\exists b \in B\mid c=g(b)$ . But if $f$ is not onto then it is possible $\exists b \in B \mid b \ne f(a)$. Only when there is no such $b$ then the composition is onto.
>
> We have reduced the proof for the general case to showing that there is not necessarily such a $b$. This is precisely the case when the codomain of $g$ is generated by the image of $f$
>
> Therefore, if $f$ is not onto, $g$ is onto, and $C = \{ g(b) : b \in \text{Im } f \}$ then $g \circ f: A \to C$ is onto

Comment: Are you trying to show that it is possible to have $g\circ f$ onto with $f$ not being onto?

Comment: Both seem to me to be nonsense, mere juggling with words.

Comment: Thats what I thought. I'm new to this stuff. Can you tell me where precisely I am making absolutely no sense

Comment: So, you want to prove that something _exists_. It this situation is enough to provide an example.

Comment: Surely to show "there is no contradiction" it's best to give an example of an $f$ and a $g$ with this property. For example $\{0\}\hookrightarrow\{0,1\}\rightarrow\{0\}$.

Comment: Your "proofs" seem more circular than "sly".  I think that the simplest proof would be an example.  This could be done with some simple functions from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I hate coming up with examples to prove these kinds of things. I feel like they cover up for my not truly understanding what is going on. That's why I'm deliberately not coming up with an example

Comment: It depends on the statement. If the statement looks like "there exists something...", then an example is enough. Actually, in this case, an example _is a proof_.

Comment: I want to establish the parameters for when the statement is true not just prove that it is true. Say I conjure a couterexample – I don't want have to have to do all the work now to show that this isn't the only counterexample. I want to explicitly understand what constitutes a counterexample and use that for my proof. Counterexamples must only work *because* they have some elusive property.

Comment: theideasmith, actually coming up with examples and counterexamples is very important in mathematics. In this case, let's say we tried to prove that $g\circ f$ surjective implies that $f$ is surjective and whatever we tried doesn't come through (obviously, since it is false). Coming up with counterexample shows that you understand why no proof can work and, more importantly, why. Secondly, the only way to prove that something is not contradictory is to give an example.

Comment: @theideasmith In this case you don't want to merely prove the statement in your lemma. You want to know which properties $f\colon A\to B$ must have in order to guarantee that $g\circ f$ is onto whenever $g\colon B\to C$ is onto. Right?

Comment: Yes. So I should restate my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if this is what you are looking for. Anyway, here is my attempt:

**Proposition**. Let $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ be functions such that $g$ is onto. Then $g\circ f$ is onto if and only if $\operatorname{im}(f)\cap g^{-1}(c)\ne\emptyset$ for all $c\in C$.

*Proof*. If $g\circ f$ is onto, then for any $c\in C$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $g\circ f(a)=c$, that is $f(a)\in g^{-1}(c)$, showing that $\operatorname{im}(f)\cap g^{-1}(c)\ne\emptyset$. Conversely, given $c\in C$, the fact that $\operatorname{im}(f)\cap g^{-1}(c)$ is nonempty allows us to pick $b\in \operatorname{im}(f)$ such that $g(b)=c$, but $b=f(a)$ for some $a\in A$, hence $g\circ f(a)=c$, showing that $g\circ f$ is onto. Q.E.D.

So, in order to show a non surjective function $f\colon A\to B$ such that $g\circ f$ is onto, it is enough to guarantee that $\operatorname{im}(f)$ intercepts $g^{-1}(c)$ for any $c\in C$. This is exactly what happens to Oscar Cunningham's example, because the function $g$ is constant.

**EDIT**. In the above proposition, $g^{-1}(c):=\{b\in B:g(b)=c\}$, while $\operatorname{im}(f)=\{b\in B:\exists a\in A$ st $f(a)=b\}$, hence $\operatorname{im}(f)\cap g^{-1}(c)=\{b\in B:\exists a\in A$ st $f(a)=b$ and $g(b)=c\}$.

Comment: @theideasmith Notice that it is necessary to ask $g$ onto because we need $g^{-1}(c)\ne\emptyset$ for all $c\in C$. Also, when $f$ is onto, the condition $\operatorname{im}(f)\cap g^{-1}(c)\ne\emptyset$ is trivially satisfied.

Comment: I get your proof except for one thing: for the second part of the proof what if you choose $c$ such that $g^{-1}(c) \not \in \text{Im } f$ because all we require is a non empty intersection, not that $g^{-1} = \text{Im }f$

Comment: @theideasmith First, $g^{-1}(c):=\{b\in B:g(b)=c\}$. In the second part we suppose that $\operatorname{im}(f)\cap g^{-1}(c)\neq \emptyset$ happens for all $c$.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't make sense to say $g^{-1}(c)\notin\text{im}(f)$ in this context. Could you rephrase your doubt, please?

Comment: By assumption, for $\text{Im }f \subset B$ and $g^{-1} \subset B$, $\text{Im f} \cap g^{-1} \ne \emptyset$. Suppose $b \in g^{-1}$ but also that $b \not\in \text{Im }f$. Then the composition is not onto. Can you very clearly explain what I am missing?

Comment: That was the issue. I was misreading $g^{-1}$ to be something else and assuming you were using notation informally.

Comment: So, are we clear now? Please, let me know if there are any further doubts.

Comment: Is your condition the same as stipulating that the codomain of $g$ is generated by the domain of $f$, that is $\text{cod }g = \{c \in C: \exists a \in A \text{ st } f(a) \in \text{im f} \cap \text{dom }g \text{ and } g(f(a)) =c \}$

Comment: It may be a nice exercise to you to answer this last question.

Comment: Is the question actually a good one or does it stem from my misunderstanding?

Comment: I don't know. Actually I think I did everything I could to clarify the answer, sorry. If you still feel that your problem is unsolved, you should edit your question and possibly reject my answer. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to explain it. Much appreciated. You really did help and I understand your answer. I just need to understand it in the context of what I expected the solution to be.

Comment: @theideasmith Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57196/discussion-between-renan-maneli-mezabarba-and-theideasmith).

Answer (score 2):

An example seems more suitable than a proof in this situation.

$A=\{a, b, c\}$, $B=\{e, f\}$, $C=\{h\}$

$f:A\rightarrow B$ defined as $f(a)=f(b)=f(c)=e$

$g:B\rightarrow C$ defined as $g(e)=g(f)=h$

Then $g\circ f:A\rightarrow C$ is surjective and $f$ is not.

Comment: How about my proof now?

Comment: You want to prove that if $g\circ f$ is onto then $f$ $\textbf{may}$ be onto, not $f$ $\textbf{must}$ be onto. How do you go about proving it?

Comment: Ok I think I figured it out

Comment: reread my comment as ``$f$ $\textbf{may}$ be not onto, not $f$ $\textbf{must}$ be not onto''